# caml query for boolean does not work properly

Tags: sharepoint-server

caml query for bool does not work, i d not know how i could work with this issue, please any help:
the result of this query is so weird: the result give me the false and true items in the same time:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
   <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='Envoye_vers_Directeur' />
     <Value Type='Boolean'>False</Value>
   </Eq>
 </Where>
</Query>
```

Comment: Use 0 instead of False, 1 instead of True.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0 instead of False. If still not working try with Type='Integer'

Comment: yeah i tried Type='Integer' but no way

Comment: Apart from that your query is fine. Double check the field name and post your code where you use this query.

Comment: There might be something else going on. Like @Naim said post your code.  You should use a 1 or 0 with Boolean fields.

Comment: Just tried this with CAML Query Builder (U2U). <Query>
   <Where>
      <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='InUse' />     <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
      </Eq>
   </Where>
</Query>
<ViewFields />
<QueryOptions />  - Worked without issue